# more DRY and succinct way to write this ruby unless statement?

Tags: ruby

I have the following:

```
unless parsed['PREDICATE'].nil?
    predicate = parsed['PREDICATE']
end
```

The logic is clear here.  But as I write it, just wondering if there's something equally clear, but more DRY?

Comment: Am I correct in my understanding that you want to execute `predicate = parsed['PREDICATE']` if `parsed` has a key `'PREDICATE'`, even if the value of that key is `nil`?

Answer (score 3):

You can write it in one line :

```
predicate = parsed['PREDICATE']  unless parsed['PREDICATE'].nil?
```

Just a [tip](https://github.com/styleguide/ruby) : Favor modifier `if`/`unless` usage when you have a *single-line* body.

Or, a guess, if you are checking if a *key* exists, and then assigning the value of the *key* to the var, then you might consider:

```
predicate = parsed['PREDICATE']  if parsed.has_key? 'PREDICATE'
```

Comment: if it fails, is predicate = nil?

Comment: Arup, I missed the second part of your answer. I would just add the advice that, when determining whether a key is present, it's good practice to use `has_key?` (aka `key?`) rather than checking to see if the value is `nil`.

Comment: My answer was the only fatality. I'm fine.